# How to generate a monthly report filling missing days of the month with zero

Tags: questdb

Let's imagine that I have the following data on a QuestDB table:

```
ts               | item
------------------------
2020-01-02T10:12 | a
2020-01-02T10:20 | b
2020-01-03T11:20 | a
2020-01-03T11:30 | b
2020-01-03T11:40 | c
```

I can execute the following query to count distinct items sampled by day for an specific month:

```sql
SELECT DAY(ts) as day, COUNT_DISTINCT(item) AS count_items
FROM my_table
WHERE ts IN '2020-01'
SAMPLE BY d FILL(0);
```

I get the following data:

```
day | count_items
------------------
2   | 2
3   | 3
```

Instead of that result I would like to have a complete monthly report (even for days where the table doesn't have data and filling them with zero) like the following:

```
day | count_items
------------------
1   | 0
2   | 2
3   | 3
4   | 0
5   | 0
6   | 0
...
31  | 0
```

Whats the best way to generate such result? I have been thinking into using JOIN with a table that generates all the days for the specific month but QuestDB does not have LEFT JOIN implemented.

Do exists a simple way to generate these kind of reports with QuestDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified Alex answer adding a `CAST(DAY(ts) AS LONG)` (without this a type error is raised in the left join condition) and using `DAYS_IN_MONTH` function:

```
SELECT x as day, COALESCE(sb.count_items, 0) AS count_items
from long_sequence(DAYS_IN_MONTH('2020-01') ls
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT CAST(DAY(ts) AS LONG) as day, COUNT_DISTINCT(item) AS count_items
   FROM my_table
   WHERE ts IN '2020-01'
   SAMPLE BY d
) AS sb ON sb.day = ls.x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with left join

```
SELECT x as day, COALESCE(sb.count_items, 0) AS count_items
from long_sequence(31) ls
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DAY(ts) as day, COUNT_DISTINCT(item) AS count_items
   FROM my_table
   WHERE ts IN '2020-01'
   SAMPLE BY d
) AS sb ON sb.day = ls.x
```

Comment: I have made some changes including the casting and replacing the long sequence call receiving `DAYS_IN_MONTH` instead of a literal. Please Alex can you approve the changes so I can set this one as the accepted answer?

Comment: @jfcalvo if this answer is helpful for you then upvote it and consider marking it as an solution. If you want to show your improvement, then add your answer. It is OK to vote and accept others and adding own answers.